# why when I export as fbx from blender it isn't keeping textures when I import it to another blender project?

Tags: texturing, export, import

I exported my model as an fbx file. I switched the path mode from auto to copy then clicked the embed textures icon. but when I export it the model is fine apart from one little thing but the textures are different. I've watched several tuts but when I follow everything they say it still doesn't work.
Here are some pics:
this is how it looks:
[image]
I export it:
[image]
I import to a new project:
[image]
This is what I get:
[image]
(Btw, the view is the same)
I also tried to unwrap the materials and bake them but still, nothing,

I got most of the textures from blender kit

Can anyone tell me if im doing something wrong? and how to export it so that the textures are there?thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Did you pack the materials and then click Limit to Selected Objects in the export menu?